# Load Python function without loading the page

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask to create an app, where I have tried implementing Follow and Unfollow people.

But, I have ran into a problem. I cannot call a Python function without calling a route from flask. Besides, Javascript, Ajax, jQuery has never been my priority, so I am entirely Pythonic.  I want my html to call this function, whenever I pressed the Follow button in html. Any help? Can I do this entirely with python or should I go for Ajax? Or any easy solution?

This is my follow bottom!

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-block"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Follow </button>


def follow():
    #my follow function
```

Comment: i believe ajax is the way to go.

Comment: What do you mean "without loading the page"? The old school ("web 1.0") way to do this would be to use a `<form>` tag that submits to your Flask route, but that would cause a new page load. If you want to do something client side, then you need to write client-side code, and that means JavaScript.

Comment: Using AJAX does not break Pythonic mentality. Your desired scenario is a good example of using AJAX to prevent reloading the whole page for a small update.